# Recategorize dummy variables by combining and excluding

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with 8 ethnicity variables that I need to change to 7, under different conditions. The respondents were instructed to choose as many ethnicities as appropriate. For example, ethnicity_2 indicates "white". Some "mixed" ethnicity people selected "white" plus another ethnicity. I want to make a new ethnicity, "white", that means the respondent chose "white" and no other ethnicity. I have taken a shot at it but it fails. Here is a portion of the code I have tried.

```
ethnicities.19 <- c("ethnicity_1", "ethnicity_2", "ethnicity_3", "ethnicity_4",
                    "ethnicity_5", "ethnicity_6", "ethnicity_7", "ethnicity_8")
bar <- foo %>%
    select(ID, ethnicity_1:ethnicity_8) %>%
    mutate(across(.cols=ethnicity_1:ethnicity_8, .fns=function(x) { ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)} )) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
     mutate(dnresp=ifelse(sum(eval(as.name(ethnicities.19)))==0, 1, 0),
##         dnresp=ifelse(!any(eval(as.name(ethnicities.19))==1), 1, 0),
            white=ifelse(eval(as.name(ethnicities.19[2]))==1 & sum(eval(as.name(ethnicities.19[-c(2)])))==0, 1, 0))
```

and so on. With this code, the `dnresp` variable gets set for nearly every case, inappropriately. And several people who chose `ethnicity_2` and other ethnicities get marked as "white".

I also tried this:

```
dnresp=ifelse(!any({{ethnicities.19}}==1), 1, 0))
```

but that tells me that all the respondents did not choose any ethnicity. And strangely enough, I get the same result from this code as well:

```
dnresp=ifelse(!any({{ethnicities.19}}==0), 1, 0))
```

Appreciate any help I can get.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
structure(list(ID = c("ATL_01", "ATL_02", "ATL_03", "ATL_04", 
"ATL_05", "ATL_06", "ATL_07", "ATL_08", "ATL_09", "ATL_10", "ATL_11", 
"ATL_12", "ATL_13", "ATL_14", "ATL_15", "ATL_16", "ATL_17", "ATL_18", 
"ATL_19", "ATL_20"), ethnicity_1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ethnicity_2 = c(1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 
NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), ethnicity_3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 
1), ethnicity_4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), ethnicity_5 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), ethnicity_6 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ethnicity_7 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ethnicity_8 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think vectorized in R. Using `rowSums` we can create a vector of havin `0` in all non-ethnicity_2 variables and `&` combine it with having `1` in ethnicity_2.

```
foo$white <- +((rowSums(foo[setdiff(ethnicities.19, 'ethnicity_2')], na.rm=TRUE) == 0) &
                 foo$ethnicity_2 == 1)
```

For non-response (I assume this is what dnrsp means) having no values at all we can use `!is.na` on the entire variable set, where we want the `rowSums` to be `0`.

```
foo$dnrsp <- +(rowSums(!is.na(foo[ethnicities.19])) == 0)
```

The `+` coerces the boolean into integer, you can also say `as.integer()`, but it's longer.

### Gives:

```
head(as.data.frame(foo))
#       ID ethnicity_1 ethnicity_2 ethnicity_3 ethnicity_4 ethnicity_5 ethnicity_6 ethnicity_7 ethnicity_8 white dnrsp
# 1 ATL_01          NA           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA     1     0
# 2 ATL_02          NA           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA     1     0
# 3 ATL_03          NA           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA     1     0
# 4 ATL_04          NA          NA           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA     0     0
# 5 ATL_05          NA           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA     1     0
# 6 ATL_06          NA          NA           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA     0     0
```